# How can to programmatically measure memory usage in an Angular Component?

Tags: angular, memory, memory-management, angular-components

I have the following Angular component, all it does is generate a grid of 2000 images and calculates the loading time. I also want to somehow calculate programmatically the memory usage. 'performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize' (I get an error saying property 'memory' does not exist on type 'performance'). Any help would be appreciated.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: `
    <div>
      <div class="load-time">Load time: {{ loadTime }} ms</div>
      <div class="load-time">Memory Usage: {{ memoryUsage }} MB</div>
      <div class="grid-container" [hidden]="isLoading">
        <div class="grid-item" *ngFor="let item of items">
          <img src="/assets/highRes.jpg" alt="placeholder image">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="isLoading">Loading...</div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
   img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
      gap: 20px;
    }
    .grid-item {
      background-color: #eee;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .load-time {
      background-color: #008000;
      color: black;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
  `]
})
export class HomeComponent {
  items = Array.from({ length: 2000 }, (_, i) => i);
  isLoading = true;
  loadTime = 0;
  memoryUsage!: number;

  ngOnInit() {

    //mark current memory usage
    performance.mark('startMeasure');
    const startTime = performance.now();
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const endTime = performance.now();
      this.loadTime = endTime - startTime;
      this.isLoading = false;
    });
  }

}
```

I tried measuring memory usage programmatically in an Angular component using 'windows.performance.memory.JSHeapSize', but it seems it no longer works.